# IOS UINavigation Bar Drop Shadow

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I am trying to add a drop shadow to a navigation bar like in the google plus app

[image]

I am adding a white background to the navigation bar with

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:whiteImage
                                  forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Where whiteImage is generated with

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(1, YES, 0.0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1, 1));    
UIImage *whiteImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But can't find a way to add the right shadow image with

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:shadowImage]];
```

Any idea how to achieve such an effect?

Comment: It's pretty straightforward; could you show the code by which you generate the `shadowImage`?

Comment: I don't know what kind of image to create in order to do it..

Comment: A simple 1x4 image will do. The image will be stretched across the width of the screen for you. Try it with a 1x4 black image and then play with it.

Comment: I already tried adding an image with the code used to create whiteImage, but that does not look like a shadow. What kind of image do you have in mind?

Comment: I _said_ play with it. Experiment! What kind of image do _you_ have in mind? It should look like a shadow! Make it kind of grey with plenty of transparency. This is not hard.

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to set the navigation bar's `clipsToBounds` to NO. That's important because otherwise the shadow image is just clipped out.